# Mapping Function Creating Blank Pages

Tags: reactjs

I copied what you had and it still populates the dropdown nicely but my other pages still won't show up.  I think it has to do with the mapping function below because if I take it out, the pages work but obviously the dropdown does not.

```js
 const MyView = CatList.map((CatList, i) => {
      return (
        <div key={i.toString()}>
          <NavDropdown.Item>{CatList.category_name}</NavDropdown.Item>
        </div>
      );
    });
```

I have a mapping function that populates my dropdown in my navbar.  It works but when I add the function, all my other pages like about us or login render blank.  I cannot figure this out.  If I take the mapping function out, the pages work.  Can someone please help me figure out why this keeps happening?

**NavMenuDesktop.jsx**

```js
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import {
  Container,
  Navbar,
  NavItem,
  MenuItem,
  Nav,
  NavDropdown,
  Form,
  FormControl,
  Button,
  Row,
  Col,
} from 'react-bootstrap';
import Logo from '../../assets/images/logo/green.png';

class NavMenuDesktop extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    const CatList = this.props.data;

    const MyView = CatList.map((CatList, i) => {
      return (
        <div key={i.toString()}>
          <NavDropdown.Item>{CatList.category_name}</NavDropdown.Item>
        </div>
      );
    });

    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Navbar bg="light" expand="lg" sticky="top">
          <Container>
            <Navbar.Brand href="/">
              <img src={Logo} className="nav-logo" />
            </Navbar.Brand>
            <Navbar.Toggle
              aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav"
              className="nav-toggler"
            >
              <i className="fa fa-bars"></i>
            </Navbar.Toggle>
            <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
              <Nav className="me-auto">
                <Nav.Link href="/">Home</Nav.Link>
                <Nav.Link href="/about">About Us</Nav.Link>
                <NavDropdown
                  title="Shop"
                  id="basic-nav-dropdown"
                  renderMenuOnMount={true}
                >
                  {MyView}
                </NavDropdown>
                <Nav.Link href="/contact">Contact</Nav.Link>

                <NavDropdown
                  title="My Account"
                  id="collasible-nav-dropdown"
                  renderMenuOnMount={true}
                >
                  <NavDropdown.Item href="/login">
                    <i className="fa fa-sign-in-alt p-2 colorred"></i>Login
                  </NavDropdown.Item>
                  <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.2">
                    <i className="fa fa-user-plus p-2 colorred"></i>Register
                  </NavDropdown.Item>
                </NavDropdown>

                <ul className="inline justify-content-right">
                  <li>
                    <Nav.Link href="/favorites">
                      <i className="fa fa-heart fa-md text-secondary"></i>
                      <sup>
                        <span className="badge text-white bgred fa-md">5</span>
                      </sup>
                    </Nav.Link>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <Nav.Link href="/cart">
                      <i className="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-md text-secondary"></i>
                      <sup>
                        <span className="badge text-white bgred fa-md">5</span>
                      </sup>
                    </Nav.Link>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </Nav>
            </Navbar.Collapse>
          </Container>
        </Navbar>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default NavMenuDesktop;
```

**HomePage.jsx**

```js
    import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
    import { Container } from 'react-bootstrap';
    import AppURL from '../api/AppURL';
    import AppRoute from '../route/AppRoute';
    import FeaturedProducts from '../components/home/FeaturedProducts';
    import Categories from '../components/home/Categories';
    import Collection from '../components/home/Collection';
    import NewArrival from '../components/home/NewArrival';
    import HomeTop from '../components/home/HomeTop';
    import NavMenuDesktop from '../components/common/NavMenuDesktop';
    import FooterDesktop from '../components/common/FooterDesktop'
    import axios from 'axios';


    class HomePage extends Component {
      
      constructor(){
        super();
        this.state ={
             MenuData:[]
        }
    }

      componentDidMount(){
        window.scroll(0,0);
        this.GetVisitorDetails();
        
          axios.get(AppURL.CategoryInfo).then(response =>{
            this.setState({MenuData:response.data});
          }).catch(error=>{

          });
      }

      GetVisitorDetails = ()=>{
        axios.get(AppURL.VisitorDetails).then().catch()
      }
      
      render() {
        return (
          <Fragment> 
         

          <NavMenuDesktop data={this.state.MenuData}/>
              
              <HomeTop />
          <Container fluid={"true"}>
                 <Categories />
                 <NewArrival />
                <FeaturedProducts />
                <Collection />
                <FooterDesktop/>
               </Container>

     </Fragment>
        )
      }
    }

    export default HomePage;
```

**AppRoute.js**

```js
    import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react'
    import { Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
    import HomePage from '../pages/HomePage';
    import UserLoginPage from '../pages/UserLoginPage';
    import ContactPage from '../pages/ContactPage';
    import AboutPage from '../pages/AboutPage';
    import ProductDetailsPage from '../pages/ProductDetailsPage';
    import FavoritePage from '../pages/FavoritePage';
    import CartPage from '../pages/CartPage';
    import PrivacyPage from '../pages/PrivacyPage';
    import RefundPage from '../pages/RefundPage';
    import PurchasePage from '../pages/PurchasePage';

    class AppRoute extends Component {
         render() {
              return (
                   <Fragment>
                        <Switch>
                             <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
                             <Route exact path="/login" component={UserLoginPage} />
                             <Route exact path="/contact" component={ContactPage} />
                             <Route exact path="/about" component={AboutPage} />
                             <Route exact path="/privacy" component={PrivacyPage} />
                             <Route exact path="/refund" component={RefundPage} />
                             <Route exact path="/purchase-guide" component={PurchasePage} />

                             <Route exact path="/productdetails" component={ProductDetailsPage} />
                             <Route exact path="/favorites" component={FavoritePage} />
                             <Route exact path="/cart" component={CartPage} />


                        </Switch>

                   </Fragment>
              )
         }
    }

    export default AppRoute
```

Comment: Can you update your question to include the NavMenuDesktop component?

Comment: I copied the wrong component.  I added NavMenuDesktop to my question

Comment: I copied what you had and it still populates the dropdown nicely but my other pages still won't show up.  I think it has to do with the mapping function below because if I take it out, the pages work but obviously the dropdown does not.

Comment: Could it be that when you map over the `CatList`, the direct child needs to be `<NavDropdown.Item key={i}>{CatList.category_name}</NavDropdown.Item>` instead of wrapping it into a div?